# Unable to implement matplotlib.pyplot.canvas.draw() for real-time plotting

Tags: matplotlib, plot, real-time

I am writing a simple python script for plotting real-time with canvas.draw() as show below. When executed it only prints the first point (1,1) and then freezes. My IDE is PyCharm if that is relevant. The same happens with a while True instead of a for loop. Pls advise

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from time import sleep

x,y=[],[]

fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot()

for i in range(10):
    x.append(i)
    y.append(i**2+1)
    ax.plot(x,y,'go')
    fig.canvas.draw()
    sleep(0.5)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Un-indent `plt.show()` and use `plt.pause(0.5)` instead of sleep

Comment: Bingo!!!! Thank you so much David.